# When uploaded file from an external program, ItemAdded is not fired

Tags: 2010, feature-receiver

I have an event receiver which works/triggered when I manually add document by click 'Add document', but the same in not working/triggered when an external application is uploading the document.

For example when I send a mail to exchange server it uploads the document behind the seen but not trigger the event.

What are things that might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to send an Email to document library where you have configured the Incoming email settings. If you want to fire an event when an email is uploaded to a document library, you need to write an event receiver derived from SPEmailEventReceiver and override EmailReceived method. [Here](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/creating-a-simple-email-receiver-for-a-document-library/) is a reference. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spemaileventreceiver.aspx) sample.